# How to hide the .jsp extension in my web server urls

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP web server, with pages that all end with the .jsp extension.

How can I hide it in my web server urls without resorting to non-java tricks (e.g., apache rewrite)?

For example:
instead of typing http://www.sample.com/search.jsp?xxx
the user would just type
http://www.sample.com/search?xxx

Answer (score 11):

You can create a servlet mapping like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>MappingServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>path/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

The url-pattern must be edited to suit your needs. You need of course to create the servlet in order to map the url to the actual jsp. This technique is used by most of the MVC frameworks.

Comment: Replace the URL-pattern tag above with a jsp-file tag and include in it's body the actual nice URL that you want...

There is no need for apache URL rewriting - the servlet spec supports exactly what you want . The proper approach is what I jyst described...

Comment: Hello !
i'm highly interested in your approach, can you elaborate a bit on it.thanks

Comment: Spring MVC for example uses this technique. You can look at the source code for the details. Spring MVC implements a full framework, so it would be a complicated solution. In the simplest form the MappingServlet will check the request path, extract the name of the view and load it from a suitable repository.

Comment: @kgiannakakis - So what would the MappingServlet look like?  I tried something like this but its not complete...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006723/generic-servlet-to-jsp-mapping

Answer (score 6):

Use this servlet mapping in your `web.xml` file.

```
<servlet>   
  <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/search.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 5):

[UrlRewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) is a good flexible Java-based framework-independent solution.

This is better than a Servlet mapping in `web.xml`, because that is too limited in what you can do, and better than an Apache based solution because it is part of your web application so you do not need to put Apache in front of your application server.

Answer (score 2):

Map the .jsp as a servlet, but use a <jsp-file> tag instead of a <url-mapping> tag.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myjsp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/myjsp.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you opt for the Apache rewrite rule, rather than the application server mapping/filter (as I did) you might also want to do more than just look for "^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$"

You may want to confirm the url is not a directory or a file that does exist if apache is fronting and serving the non-jsp resources.  And confirm that the JSP exists, and do a pass thru rather than redirect, and append any possible query string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*\.(jsp)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.jsp -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.jsp [PT,QSA,L]
```

And to make sure that users only see this via /search, not /search.jsp then you want to rewrite the reverse as well

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jsp$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)index$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This is a good idea for SEO purposes so that search engines dont ding you for duplicating content at multiple urls.

Answer (score 1):

I have a jsp located at data/feed.jsp
Adding this to my web.xml meant I could access it at data/feed ...

```
<servlet>   
  <servlet-name>feed</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/data/feed.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>feed</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/data/feed</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$  $1.jsp
```

In your .htaccess should rewrite all URLs to .jsp. So search.jsp will just be search, as you described.

Comment: I'm no regex pro, but won't this only work if the jsp file contains letters or numbers in the name? For example, `advanced-search.jsp` won't work.

Comment: @styfle... yes... add \- before ] to support hyphens

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JSP expert but I think you can define URL-mappings in web.xml to provide aliases for your servlets and jsps.