# Hide JSP extension from web pages

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee, struts2

Im developing a web application(J2EE,Struts2,JSP,Tomcat)
I want to hide the .jsp extension from webpages.

here is some piece of my web.xml:

```
     <filter>
         <filter-name>STSDispatcher</filter-name>
         <filter-class>
           org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
         </filter-class>
     </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>STSDispatcher</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
```

I Googled around and found this solution:

```
    <servlet>  
         <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>  
         <jsp-file>myJSPfile.jsp</jsp-file>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
         <servlet-name>myFoo</servlet-name>  
         <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I tried this like below, but didn't work:

for example I have "**alert.jsp**" and this is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>alert</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/alert.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet> 

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>alert</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/alert</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

but I got this error:
**"There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name alert. - [unknown location]"**

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get the error because your struts2 filter intercept all the request coming to the server and tries to find a mapping in your actions but since `/alert` actually points to a servlet you see the error.
A solution would be to have the mapping in your struts config file like:

```
<action name="alert">
    <result>/alert.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This way when you request `/alert` you get the page with no extension (name of your action).

Comment: Yeah, I got this solution and I wanted to post it here, but you made it easier for me ;) Thank you buddy.

Answer (score 5):

You can put the directory structure with the JSPs in WEB-INF, then use a servlet to forward to the JSPs according to the requested URL.

The servlet will be mapped to a wildcard pattern, like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ForwardToJspServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.page</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ForwardToJspServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the logic of the servlet will be converting the requested URL to the path of the JSP and then forwarding.

For example, the user requests the URL **/yourApp/documents/documentAdd.page** and you forward to the JSP under **/WEB-INF/JSP/documents/documentAdd.jsp**.

Comment: I guess the error has something to do with the filter mapping to ALL URLs (`/*`). As an application could use something else than Struts for some URSs, a good practice would be to use a pattern for your Struts actions, like `*.do` or `/actions/*`, so URLs that don't follow the pattern won't be picked up by Struts (and maybe cause an error).

Answer (score 2):

[Try UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Comment: Holy mother of god! It works fine, BUTTTT in my login page(welcome file) I lost some of my images when I use that method with a defined rule for that page!!!!!! WHY?!!

Answer (score 0):

That method should actually work. Other alternative is editing htaccess file, add this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$  $1.jsp
```

Any xyz.jsp would be xyz after doing this. I actually found this method few days back at 
[How to hide the .jsp extension in my web server urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460288/how-to-hide-the-jsp-extension-in-my-web-server-urls)

Comment: what if he does not have an Apache web server?

Comment: surampudi: thanks buddy but where is this ".htaccess"?!
I'm using Tomcat6+struts2 and in eclipse ide.