# Generic Servlet to JSP Mapping

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-mapping

I have a web app with many JSP files and want to remove the .jsp extensions from displaying in the URL without having to map each servlet to a similar page name.  To do this I would like to redirect all servlets to a JSP file in a generic manner such as mapping /Login to /Login.jsp.
I mapped all servlets to a filter as below.  This works with respect to redirections to *.jsp except the end result is a blank page with the URL still containing the .jsp extension.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PageNameFilter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>PageName</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PageNameFilter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


public class PageName extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();

        if (!uri.endsWith(".jsp"))
        {
            String newPage = uri + ".jsp";

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(newPage);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            // Here when we have a full URL (ie: /Login.jsp)

            // ??? WHAT TO DO HERE ???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not map your JSP's in your web app's web.xml file? Use <jsp-file>/test.jsp</jsp-file> for example.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to map each jsp file to a servlet if possible.  I have 150+ JSP files and that will be a bear to maintain.

Comment: It is not hard to do. You don't map to a Servlet. You map each JSP file to a name that will be its url-pattern.

Comment: Then there's the maintenance of 150 * 2 (map and servlet) configurations, adds, deletes, name changes, etc.   If it can't be automated in Tomcat I guess it needs to be done with an Apache bridge and re-write rule.

Comment: So I tried adding a mapping for each jsp file, I generated them with a command line script and pasted the 300 new entries into web.xml.  I tested one mapping and it worked.  At 300 Tomcat craps the bed.  It doesn't start and the jsp compiler finds problems that don't exist in the code.

Comment: Did you look at Tomcat's logs? You might have an error in the xml. Also, try opening web.xml file in IE browser. You might be able to see problem with the xml .

Comment: Got it working.  I found a bug in my mapping script and the compiler that wasn't handling expressions enclosed by <%= %> within the value of a custom tag.

Comment: This is working but under Eclipse, Tomcat 8 sometimes takes longer than 45 sec to start up.  Other times it takes less than 3.  Also sometimes Tomcat can't find the custom tag classes and I have to clean and rebuild the project up to 2 times.  If I remove the 300+ mapping entries from web.xml Tomcat starts quickly although occasionally I get the class not found error for the custom tag class and have to rebuild.  That has been happening for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did this dynamically without servlet mappings using tuckey's urlrewrite.  See the SO post here [urlrewrite example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071157/urlrewritefilter-rule-to-remove-jsp-file-extention)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by automating the servlet mapping.  So it comes down to running a script and a cut/past of the mappings into Web.xml.  This script (windows cmd) generates a file named servletmap.xml with the mappings to include.

```
@echo off

set outFile=servletmap.xml

echo. > %outFile%


for /f %%i in ('dir ..\WebContent\*.jsp /b') do (

echo %%~ni

echo   ^<servlet^> >> %outFile%
echo     ^<servlet-name^>%%~ni^</servlet-name^> >> %outFile%
echo     ^<jsp-file^>/%%i^</jsp-file^> >> %outFile%
echo   ^</servlet^> >> %outFile%
echo   ^<servlet-mapping^> >> %outFile%
echo     ^<servlet-name^>%%~ni^</servlet-name^> >> %outFile%
echo     ^<url-pattern^>/%%~ni^</url-pattern^> >> %outFile%
echo   ^</servlet-mapping^> >> %outFile%

echo. >> %outFile%
echo. >> %outFile%
)
```