# How to fix DOM based Cross-Site Scripting in JSP file

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, applet, xss

Hope you doing well...!
We are using applet based application. Here the problem is I need to fix the DOM based Cross-Site Scripting in on of the JSP file.
how this is happening is, Hacker are tying to inject the payload to the URL. In other words manipulating the URL.
Original URL `http://rs123.mt.att.com:8001/w4/query.jsp`
Manipulated URL `http://rs123.mt.att.com:8001/w4/query.jsp?option=%3E%22%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281702%29%3C%2Fscript%3E&cloption=%3E%22%2 7%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%281702%29%3C%2Fscript%3E`
How can I restrict this ??
Even i tried using libraries also, unfortunately that is not helping in this case as this client based file.
Here am attaching query.jsp file.

```
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" import="java.net.*, glbl.jtn.*" %>

<%@ include file="getnetinfo.jsp" %>
<%! boolean RFlag ;%>


<%
  String cl = "",line="";
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/topnet/etc/177141e_cb"));
//String cl = "";
cl = "N";
cl = input.readLine();
/*while((line = input.readLine())!= null)
{
    if (!(line.startsWith("#")))
        cl= line;
}*/
%>

<% 
    Date date = new Date(); 
    String option = request.getParameter("option"); 
    String cloption = request.getParameter("cloption"); 
    String toption = request.getParameter("toption"); 
    String title = "",ffile = "", sfile = "";   
    int row1 = 0,row2 = 0,row3 = 0,row4 = 0,row5 = 0;   
    boolean allFlag=false;
    boolean result=false;
    System.out.println("user");
    
    if (option.equals("verify")) {
        row1 = 50;
        row2 = 0;
        row3 = 30;  
        row4 = 20;
        row5 = 30;
        title = "Select NSA Switch CLLI";   
    }
    else if(option.equals("rc")) {
                row1 = 100;
                row2 = 0;
                row3 = 20;
                row4 = 10;
                row5 = 20;
                title = "RC BUNDLE QUERY";
        }
    }
    else if(option.equals("cptan")) {
        row1 = 90;
        row2 = 0;
        row3 = 25;  
        row4 = 20;
        row5 = 25;
        title = "Select 4E Trunk by TAN/OTAN";
    }   
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache;">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" src="cllimatch.js"> </script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="GetAllStream.js"> </script>
<script language="JavaScript" >
var localArray = new Array();
var genericArray = new Array();
var isSwLocal = false;
var winversion=0 ;
var browser = "netscape";
var fmtFile = "";
var sortFile = "";
//var allFlag = false;
var RFlag=false;

var webhost =window.location.hostname;
var userid ='<%= uid%>';
<%
String userid =uid;
String webhost =java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
allFlag = GetAllStream.isAllStream(userid,webhost);
%>
if ((navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase()).lastIndexOf("win") != -1) {
    winversion=1 ;
}
else {
    winversion=0 ;
}

if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
    browser = "IE";
function loadLocalArray(str) {
        localArray = str.split(",");
}

function loadGenricArray(str) {
        genericArray = str.split(",");
}

function showBody1() {
     var cll = '<%= cl%>';
    var body1doc = parent.body1.document;
    body1doc.open();
    body1doc.writeln("<% if(option.equals("clfi")) { %>");
    body1doc.writeln('<html><body text=#000000 bgcolor=#d3d3d3 leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 onload=\'parent.loadClliArray(<%= getString(sw4eList) %>); parent.loadClliAlias(<%= getString(aliasList) %>); parent.loadLocalArray(<%= getString(local4eList) %>); parent.loadGenricArray(<%= getString(swGenList) %>); document.form1.desig.focus(); \'>');
    body1doc.writeln("<%} if(option.equals("clcid")) { %>");
    body1doc.writeln('<html><body text=#000000 bgcolor=#d3d3d3 leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 onload=\'parent.loadClliArray(<%= getString(sw4eList) %>); parent.loadClliAlias(<%= getString(aliasList) %>); parent.loadLocalArray(<%= getString(local4eList) %>); parent.loadGenricArray(<%= getString(swGenList) %>); document.form1.tfn.focus(); \'>');
    body1doc.writeln("<%} else { %>");
    body1doc.writeln('<html><body text=#000000 bgcolor=#d3d3d3 leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 onload=\'parent.loadClliArray(<%= getString(sw4eList) %>); parent.loadClliAlias(<%= getString(aliasList) %>); parent.loadLocalArray(<%= getString(local4eList) %>); parent.loadGenricArray(<%= getString(swGenList) %>); document.form1.ssclcid.focus(); \'>');
    body1doc.writeln("<%}%>");
    body1doc.writeln("<center>");
    body1doc.writeln("<form method=post name=form1>");
    body1doc.writeln("<table>");
    body1doc.writeln("<% if(option.equals("insvcssclcid")) { %>");
    body1doc.writeln("<tr>");
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B>SS CLCID:</B></td>");
    if(cll == "Y")
    {
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='left'><B><input type='text' name='ssclcid' value='' size=24 ></B></td>");
    }
    else
    {
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='left'><B><input type='text' name='ssclcid' value='' size=24 maxlength=24 ></B></td>");
    }
    body1doc.writeln("</tr>");
    body1doc.writeln("<tr>");
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B>End point CLLI:</B></td>");
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='left'><B><input type='text' name='aclli' value='' size=11 maxlength=11></B></td>");
    body1doc.writeln("</tr>");
    body1doc.writeln("<% } %>");
    body1doc.writeln("<% if(!option.equals("cltgi") && !option.equals("clcid") && !option.equals("clfi") && !option.equals("cptan") &&  !option.equals("insvcssclcid")) { %>");
    body1doc.writeln("<tr>");
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B>Switch CLLI:</B></td>");
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='left'><B><input type='text' name='aclli' value='' size=11 maxlength=11></B></td>");
    body1doc.writeln("</tr>");
    body1doc.writeln("<% } %>");
    body1doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B>SS_CLCID:</B></td>");
function showBody4(opt) {
    var body4doc = parent.body1.document;
    var cpinsTanW;
    body4doc.open();
    body4doc.writeln("<html><body text='#000000' bgcolor='#d3d3d3' leftmargin=0 topmargin=0>");
    body4doc.writeln("<center>");
    body4doc.writeln("<form method=post name=form4>");
    body4doc.writeln("<table>");

    if (opt=="tan") {
        cpinsTanW=window.open("/w4eqry/query.jsp?option=cptan&toption=tan","_blank","scrollbars,resizable,status,width=420,height=220,left=0,top=0,screenx=50,screeny=300");
        cpinsTanW.focus();
        top.close();

    }
    else if (opt=="otan") {
        cpinsTanW=window.open("/w4eqry/query.jsp?option=cptan&toption=otan","_blank","scrollbars,resizable,status,width=420,height=220,left=0,top=0,screenx=50,screeny=300");
        cpinsTanW.focus();
        top.close();

    }
    
    body4doc.writeln("</table>");
    body4doc.writeln("</form>");
    body4doc.writeln("<center>");
    body4doc.writeln("</body></html>");
    body4doc.close();
}   

function showBody3() {
    var body3doc = parent.body3.document;
    
    
    body3doc.open();
    
    
    var allf = '<%= allFlag %>';
    body3doc.writeln("<html><body text='#000000' bgcolor='#d3d3d3' leftmargin=0 topmargin=0>");
    if(winversion == 0)         // for solaris only
    { 
                body3doc.writeln("<style type=text/css>");
                body3doc.writeln("input, button {");
                body3doc.writeln("font: bold small Verdana;");
                body3doc.writeln("background-color: #FFCC99;");
                body3doc.writeln("color: #00008A;");
                body3doc.writeln("}");
                body3doc.writeln("</style>");
     }
    body3doc.writeln("<center>");
    body3doc.writeln("<form method=post name=form3>");
    body3doc.writeln("<table>");
    body3doc.writeln("<table>");
    body3doc.writeln("<% if(!option.equals("cltgi") && !option.equals("clcid") && !option.equals("clfi") && !option.equals("rc") && !option.equals("cptan")) { %>");
    body3doc.writeln("<tr>");
    
    if(allf == "true")
    {
        //alert('ALLF1 ==='+allf);
        body3doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B><input type='button' name='matchclli' value='Match SW CLLI' onClick='parent.allMatchClli(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli);'></B></td>"); 
    }
    else
    {
        //alert('ALLF2 ==='+allf);
        body3doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B><input type='button' name='matchclli' value='Match SW CLLI' onClick='parent.matchClli(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli);'></B></td>"); 
    }
    body3doc.writeln("<% if(!option.equals("verify") && !option.equals("selord") && !option.equals("cptan") && !option.equals("insvcssclcid")) { %>");  
    if(allf == "true")
    {
        body3doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B><input type='button' name='matchclli' value='Match FE CLLI' onClick='parent.allMatchClli(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli);'></B></td>"); 
    }
   if( cll == "Y")
    {
    body3doc.writeln("<% if(option.equals("insvcssclcid") || option.equals("ssclcid") ) { %>");
    body3doc.writeln("<td><B><input type='button' name='Help' value='Help' onClick='parent.do_help()'></B></td>");
    body3doc.writeln("<% } %>");
    }
    body3doc.writeln("</tr>");
    body3doc.writeln("<% } %>");
    body3doc.writeln("<% if(option.equals("cltgi") || option.equals("clcid") || option.equals("clfi")) { %>");
    body3doc.writeln("<tr>");
    if(allf == "true"){
        body3doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B><input type='button' name='matchclli' value='Match A' onClick='parent.allMatchClli(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli);'></B></td>"); 
        body3doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B><input type='button' name='matchclli' value='Match Z' onClick='parent.allMatchClli(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli);'></B></td>"); 

    }
    else
    {
        body3doc.writeln("<td align='right'><B><input type='button' name='matchclli' value='Match CLLI' onClick='parent.matchClli(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli);'></B></td>"); 
    }
    body3doc.writeln("<td><B><input type='button' name='execute' value='Search' onClick='parent.doExecution()'></B></td>");
    body3doc.writeln("<td><B><input type='button' name='Quit' value='Quit' onClick='top.close()'></B></td>");   
    body3doc.writeln("</tr>");
    body3doc.writeln("<% } %>");
    body3doc.writeln("</table>");
    body3doc.writeln("</form>");
    body3doc.writeln("<center>");
    body3doc.writeln("</table>");
    body3doc.writeln("</form>");
    body3doc.writeln("<center>");
    body3doc.writeln("</body></html>");
    body3doc.close();
}

function getSelectedRadioValue(buttonGroup) 
{
  for (var i=0; i<buttonGroup.length; i++) 
  {
    if (buttonGroup[i].checked) 
    {
      return buttonGroup[i].value;
    }
  }
  return "A";
}

function getRadioValue()
{
    if ((parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.wchswch))=="aend")
        RFlag=false;
    else
        RFlag=true;
    //alert("RFlag in getRadioValue-->     "+RFlag);
}

function doFormat() 
{
    <%  
                ffile = "/tmp/" + uid + date.getTime()+ ".w4ewl";
    %>  
    var fileName = '<%= ffile %>';
    var win;
    var myUrl="/cgi-bin/w4edispfmt/WL/trans?file="+escape(fileName);
    win = window.open(myUrl,"<%= date.getTime() %>","resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status,width=640,height=750");
    fmtFile = '<%= uid + date.getTime() %>';
}

function doSort() 
{
    <%  
                sfile = "/tmp/" + uid + date.getTime()+ ".w4esort";
    %>  
    var fileName = '<%= sfile %>';
    var win;
    var myUrl="/cgi-bin/w4eprovsort/trans?file="+escape(fileName);
    win = window.open(myUrl,"<%= date.getTime() %>","resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status,width=450,height=550");
    sortFile = '<%= uid + date.getTime() %>';
}
function is4eLocal(clli) 
{
    
    var i;
    var localClli;  
    var sClli;
    sClli = clli.toUpperCase();
    
    for (i=0; i<localArray.length; i++) 
    {
        var index = localArray[i].indexOf(sClli);   
        
        if(index >= 12) 
        {
            localClli = localArray[i].substr(0,11); 
            isSwLocal = true;
            
        }
        else if(index != -1) 
        {   
            localClli = localArray[i].substr(12,localArray[i].length);
        }
    }
    
    return localClli;
}

function getGeneric(clli) 
{
    var i;
    var generic;    
    var sClli;
    sClli = clli.toUpperCase();
    
    for (i=0; i<genericArray.length; i++) 
    {
        var index = genericArray[i].indexOf(sClli); 
        
        if(index != -1) 
            generic = genericArray[i].substr(genericArray[i].indexOf(":")+1,genericArray[i].length);
    }
    return generic;
}

function getActionCode() 
{
    var actcode = "";
    
    var actType = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.actioncode);
    if(actType == "Chg") 
        actcode = "C";
    else if(actType == "Add")
        actcode = "A";
    else if(actType == "Disc")
        actcode = "D";
    else 
        actcode = "";
    return actcode;
}

function validateCustomer() 
{
    parent.showMessage(""); 
    var cust = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.customer);  
    
    if(cust == "ALL") 
    {
        parent.showMessage("Customer ID/Name is required...");
        return "false";
    }
    else if(cust == "Id") 
    {
        var cusid = parent.body2.document.form2.custid.value ;
        if(cusid == "" || cusid.length == 0) 
        {
            parent.showMessage("Customer ID is required...");
            return "false"; 
        } 
    }
    else if(cust == "Name") 
    {
        var cusnme = parent.body2.document.form2.custname.value ;
        if(cusnme == "" || cusnme.length == 0) 
        {
            parent.showMessage("Customer Name is required...");
            return "false"; 
        } 
    }
    return cust;
}

function validatetfn(tfn) 
{
    parent.showMessage(""); 
    var tfnVal;
    tfnVal = tfn.value;
    tfn.value=tfn.value.toUpperCase();
    
    if(tfnVal == "" || tfnVal.length == 0) 
    {   
        parent.showMessage("Number is required... ");
        return false;   
    }   
    return true;
}

function validateclfi(clfi) 
{
    parent.showMessage(""); 
    clfi.value = clfi.value.toUpperCase();
    if(clfi.value == "" || clfi.value.length == 0) 
    {   
        parent.showMessage("Alphanumeric is required... ");
        return false;   
    }   
    return true;
}

function validatessclcid(ssclcid) 
{
    parent.showMessage(""); 
    ssclcid.value = ssclcid.value.toUpperCase();
    if(ssclcid.value == "" || ssclcid.value.length == 0) 
    {   
        parent.showMessage("CLCID_SS is required... ");
        return false;   
    }   
    return true;
}
function trim(str) 
{
   return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
function resize() {
alert("inside resize()");
 }

function do_help() 
{
   
  helpWin=window.open("/help/reports_help.htm","RPT_ISDN_HELP","scrollbars,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable,width=600,height=780") ;
  helpWin.focus() ;
}
function doExecution() 
{
    parent.showMessage(""); 
    var win;
    var qryWinName = '<%= option %>';   
    var userid = '<%= uid %>';
    var debug = '<%= debug %>'; 
    var webhost=window.location.hostname;
    var allf = '<%= allFlag %>';
    //var cflag = false;
    if(qryWinName =="clcid") 
    {
        var swType = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.wchswch); 
        var swclli = parent.body1.document.form1.aclli;
        var feclli = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli;
        var cllia =swclli.value;
        var clliz=feclli.value;
        
        if(swType == "aend") 
        {
            if(parent.validateClli(swclli) != true)
            {
                if(allf == "true")
                {
                    if(parent.allMatchClli(swclli) == false)
                        parent.showMessage("A End CLLI must be an Allstream CLLI");
                }   
                return;
            }   
        }
        if(allf != "true") 
        { 
            if(parent.validateFeClli(feclli) != true)
                return;
            parent.showMessage("");
        }
    
        if(swType == "zend") 
        {
            if(parent.validateClli(feclli) != true)
            {
                if(allf == "true")
                {
                    if(parent.allMatchClli(feclli) == false)
                        parent.showMessage("Z End CLLI must be an Allstream CLLI");
                }
                return;
            }
            if(allf != "true") 
            { 
                if(parent.validateFeClli(swclli) != true) 
                    return;
                parent.showMessage("");
            }
        }   
        
        var wid = 950;
        var ht = 560;   
        var htfile = "w4eitmrpt.ht";
        var cloption = '<%= cloption %>';
        if(cloption == "insvc") 
        {   
            htfile = "w4einsvc.ht";
            wid = 500;
            ht = 650;
        }
        if(cloption == "cpinsvc") 
        {   
            htfile = "w4ecpinsvc.ht";
            var generic = parent.getGeneric(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value);   
            wid = 950;
            ht = 950;
        }
        var clType = "T";   
        if(parent.validatetfn(parent.body1.document.form1.tfn) == true) 
        {   
            var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file="+escape(htfile)+"&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&tfn="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.tfn.value)+"&swType="+escape(swType)+"&option="+escape(clType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
            win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width="+wid+",height="+ht);
            top.close();
        }   
        return;
    }   

    if(qryWinName =="clfi") 
    {
        var swType = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.wchswch); 
        var swclli = parent.body1.document.form1.aclli;
        var feclli = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli;
        var cllia =swclli.value;
        var clliz=feclli.value;
        if(swType == "aend") 
        {
            if(parent.validateClli(swclli) != true)
            {
                if(allf == "true")
                {
                    if(parent.allMatchClli(swclli) == false)
                        parent.showMessage("A End CLLI must be an Allstream CLLI");
                }
                return;
            }   
        }
        if(allf != "true") 
        { 
            if(parent.validateFeClli(feclli) != true)
                return;
            parent.showMessage("");
        }
    
        if(swType == "zend") 
        {
            if(parent.validateClli(feclli) != true)
            {
                if(allf == "true")
                {
                    if(parent.allMatchClli(feclli) == false)
                        parent.showMessage("Z End CLLI must be an Allstream CLLI");
                }
                return;
            }   
            if(allf != "true") 
            {   
                if(parent.validateFeClli(swclli) != true)
                    return;
                parent.showMessage("");
            }
        var wid = 950;
        var ht = 560;   
        var htfile = "w4eitmrpt.ht";
        var clType = "F";   
        if(parent.validateclfi(parent.body1.document.form1.desig) == true && parent.validateclfi(parent.body1.document.form1.type) == true) 
        {   
            var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file="+escape(htfile)+"&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&type="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.type.value)+"&desig="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.desig.value)+"&swType="+escape(swType)+"&option="+escape(clType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
            win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width="+wid+",height="+ht);
            top.close();
        }   
        return; 
    }
    
    if(qryWinName =="cltgi") 
    {
        var swType = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.wchswch); 
        var swclli = parent.body1.document.form1.aclli;
        var feclli = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli;
        if(swType == "aend") 
        {
            if(parent.validateClli(swclli) != true)
            {
                if(allf == "true")
                {
                    if(parent.allMatchClli(swclli) == false)
                        parent.showMessage("A End CLLI must be an Allstream CLLI");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        if(allf != "true") 
        {
            if(parent.validateFeClli(feclli) != true) 
                return;
            parent.showMessage("");
        }
    
        if(swType == "zend") 
        {
            if(parent.validateClli(feclli) != true)
            {
                if(allf == "true")
                {
                    if(parent.allMatchClli(feclli) == false)
                        parent.showMessage("Z End CLLI must be an Allstream CLLI");
                }
                return;
            }
            if(allf != "true") 
            { 
                if(parent.validateFeClli(swclli) != true)
                    return;
                parent.showMessage("");
            }
            
        var wid = 500;
        var ht = 650;   
        var htfile = "w4einsvc.ht";
        var cloption = '<%= cloption %>';
        if(cloption == "cpinsvc")
        {
            var generic = parent.getGeneric(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value);   
            htfile = "w4ecpinsvc.ht";
            var wid = 950;
            var ht = 950;   

        }
        var clType = "G";   
        var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file="+escape(htfile)+"&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&tfn="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.tfn.value)+"&swType="+escape(swType)+"&option="+escape(clType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
        win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width="+wid+",height="+ht);
        top.close();
        return;
    }   
    if(qryWinName =="cptan") 
    {
        var swclli = parent.body1.document.form1.aclli;
        if(parent.validateClli(swclli) != true)
                return;
                
        var generic = parent.getGeneric(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value);   
        var wid = 950;
        var ht = 950;   
        var htfile = "c.ht";
        htfile = "w4ecpinsvc.ht";
        var generic = parent.getGeneric(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value);   
        var clType = "O";   
        var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file="+escape(htfile)+"&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&ep_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&tan="+ escape(parent.body1.document.form1.tan.value)+"&option="+escape(clType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
        win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width="+wid+",height="+ht);
        top.close();
        return;
    }   
    
    
    if(parent.validateClli(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli) == true) 
    {
        
        var lclClli = parent.is4eLocal(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value);
        
        var generic = parent.getGeneric(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value);   
        
        if(qryWinName =="insvcssclcid") 
        {
            var htfile = "w4einsvc.ht";
            var cloption = '<%= cloption %>';
            if(cloption == "cpinsvc")   
                htfile = "w4ecpinsvc.ht";
            var clType = "S";   
            
            
            if(parent.validatessclcid(parent.body1.document.form1.ssclcid) == true) 
            {   
                var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file="+escape(htfile)+"&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&ep_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&ssclcid='"+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.ssclcid.value)+"'&option="+escape(clType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
                if(cloption == "cpinsvc")
                {
                    win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=950,height=950");
                }
                else
                    win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=500,height=650");
                    top.close();
            }   
            return;
        }   
        
        parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value.toUpperCase(); 
        
        if(qryWinName =="ssclcid") 
        {
            var feclli = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli;
            if(parent.validateFeClli(feclli) != true)   
                return; 
            var htfile = "w4eitmrpt.ht";
            var clType = "S";   
            if(parent.validatessclcid(parent.body1.document.form1.ssclcid) == true) 
            {   
                var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file="+escape(htfile)+"&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&ssclcid='"+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.ssclcid.value)+"'&option="+escape(clType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
                win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=930,height=560");
                top.close();
            }   
            return;
        }   
        
        if(qryWinName =="nct") 
        {
            var feclli = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value;
            if(feclli == "" || feclli.length == 0) 
            {
                parent.showMessage("Far End CLLI is required... ");
                return; 
            }
    
            if(parent.validateBtfn(parent.body1.document.form1.btfn) == true) 
            {   
                var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file=w4enctdisp.ht&uid="+escape(userid)+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&btfn="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.btfn.value)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&generic="+escape(generic);
                win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=900,height=870");
                top.close();
                
            }
            else
            { 
                return;
            }
        }   
        var trknType = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body1.document.form1.trunkType); 
        var intlType;
        
        if(trknType == "INTL")
            intlType = parent.getSelectedRadioValue(parent.body2.document.form2.serviceType);   
        
        if(qryWinName =="all") 
        {
            var feclli = parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value;
            if( (feclli != "") && ( (trim(feclli)).length != 0) )
            {
                
                if(validateFeClli(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli) == false )
                {
                    return;
                }
                    
            }

            var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file=w4ewldisp.ht&uid="+escape(userid)+"&option=all"+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&trk_type="+escape(trknType)+"&intl_type="+escape(intlType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&ffile="+escape(fmtFile)+"&sfile="+escape(sortFile)+"&$TITLE=ALL%20ORDERS"+"&generic="+escape(generic);
                
                if(browser == "IE")
                    win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=970,height=590");                 
                else
                    win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=955,height=560");
            
                top.close();
            
                return;
        }   
        
        if(qryWinName =="coorddisc") 
        {
            var myUrl="/cgi-bin/espserve?file=w4ewldisp.ht&uid="+escape(userid)+"&option=coorddisc"+"&isSwLocal="+escape(isSwLocal)+"&sw_name="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.aclli.value)+"&fe_clli="+escape(parent.body1.document.form1.zclli.value)+"&lcl_clli="+escape(lclClli)+"&trk_type="+escape(trknType)+"&intl_type="+escape(intlType)+"&debug="+escape(debug)+"&ffile="+escape(fmtFile)+"&sfile="+escape(sortFile)+"&$TITLE=COORD.DISCS%26ADDS"+"&generic="+escape(generic);
            
            if(browser == "IE")
                win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=970,height=590");
            else
                win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=955,height=560");
            
            top.close();
            return;
        }   
                if(browser == "IE")
                win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=970,height=590");
            else
                win = window.open(myUrl,"_blank","scrollbars,status,width=955,height=560");
            
            top.close();
            return;
        }           
    }
}
    
</script>   
    </head>
    <title><%= title %></title> 
    
    <frameset border=0 rows="<%= row1 %>,<%= row2 %>,<%= row3%>,<%= row4 %>,<%= row5 %>">
    <frame src="javascript:parent.showBody1();" name="body1" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no>
    <frame src="javascript:parent.showBody2('qry','N');" name="body2" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no>
    <frame src="javascript:parent.showBody3();" name="body3" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no>
    <!frame src="javascript:parent.showBody4('qry');" name="body4" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no>
    <frame src="javascript:parent.showMessage('');" name="msgbody" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no>
    <frame src="javascript:parent.showFooter();" name="footer" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: did you tried with `.htaccess` ?

Comment: @Swati , hope you doing well and thanks for your time.. But am so sorry, I didn't understand your point...

Comment: @Swati, any information is useful for me...!

Comment: By using `.htaccess` you can restrict user from manipulating url and url parameter for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538820/10606400) .You can get more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/821-0980/bhaka/index.html).